# My onkeypress in python turtle not working

Tags: python, python-turtle

So im working on something very basic in pycharm and my onkeypress wont work. What i mean is that when i press w, s, Up or Down, nothing happens.

Here is the code:

```
# Functions
def paddle_a_up():
 y = paddle_a.ycor()
 y += 20
 paddle_a.sety(y)

def paddle_a_down():
 y = paddle_a.ycor()
 y -= 20
 paddle_a.sety(y)

def paddle_b_up():
 y = paddle_b.ycor()
 y += 20
 paddle_b.sety(y)

def paddle_b_down():
 y = paddle_b.ycor()
 y -= 20
 paddle_b.sety(y)

# Keyboard binding
wn.listen()
wn.onkeypress(paddle_a_up(), "w")
wn.onkeypress(paddle_a_down(), "s")
wn.onkeypress(paddle_b_up(), "Up")
wn.onkeypress(paddle_b_down(), "Down")
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45545469/turtle-onkeypress-not-working-python

Answer (score 1):

This is a common beginner's error with turtle events.  In these calls:

```
wn.onkeypress(paddle_a_up(), "w")
wn.onkeypress(paddle_a_down(), "s")
wn.onkeypress(paddle_b_up(), "Up")
wn.onkeypress(paddle_b_down(), "Down")
```

you should be passing the names of your functions to call *later*, when the event occurs, not calling them yourself.  It should be:

```
wn.onkeypress(paddle_a_up, "w")
wn.onkeypress(paddle_a_down, "s")
wn.onkeypress(paddle_b_up, "Up")
wn.onkeypress(paddle_b_down, "Down")
```

Comment: wow, worked perfectly. but what do u mean with " _passing the names of your functions to call later, when the event occurs, not calling them yourself_"??? i didn't quite understand that.

Comment: @telemaster, a function is another datatype, like `int`, it can be stored and passed around.  Event handler setup fuctions like `onkeypress` take a function as an argument to call if/when the particular key, e.g. `"Down"`, is pressed.  By including parentheses, you called the `paddle_b_down()` function, you instead needed to pass the `paddle_b_down` function.